# Use linux grep to find emails

Tags: regex, linux, grep

If this question has been asked and answered before, my apologies. I couldn't find anything from looking.

How can I use linux grep / regex to find unknown characters in an email address? For example, let's say we had this list:

> userone:123456@example.com
>
> usertwo:123@example.com
>
> userthree:12@example.com

how could I grep the list to find emails matching `***@example.com`?
(the only email that should be found from this is 123@example.com)

I'm aware that `grep -e '...@example\.com'` would work, but periods can represent **any** characters in grep, so doing this would also find `:12@example.com`. Plus, MOST email address don't contain just any character, they are typically confined to letters, numbers, periods, and underscores (many email providers don't allow anything else)

I need to use something else besides a period symbol in grep, something like [a-Z0-9._] so that letters, numbers, periods, and underscores are included but nothing else. I'm unsure of how to go about this. Thanks

EDIT: What I've tried so far:
`grep -e '[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{3}@example.com' *`. This doesn't work, so it comes down to just me getting the regex wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for a regular expression to match any upper or lowercase character, digit, period, or underscore?

Comment: If you need to match a literal period, you can escape it with a backslash: `\.`. Your question seems to have to do with regex basics. I would suggest looking at an informational site such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/ or experimenting on regex101.com.

Comment: Yes, but in this example only for 3 characters, so I can use something else instead of "..."

Comment: Real email addresses _can_, in fact, contain _any_ character; don't confuse that with what most places "typically" do. I commonly have `+` in email addresses. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: how about just `grep '123@example.com'` then. you do not need any regular expression.

Comment: The thing is, `userthree:12@example.com` is itself a valid email address. How can you know to exclude that?  Is it always the case that there is, for example `<username> <colon> <email_address>`? Then you'd be able to use that fact in your matching `grep -E ':(...@example.com)`. Do the addresses always start at the start of a line? You could use that knowledge too.

Comment: no, there could be spaces instead of colons. <username> <space> <email address>

Comment: Additionally, for longer emails, such as 123456789123456789@example.com, grepping ..................@example.com would find things before the start of the email. like: `1111: userfour11@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

If the email addresses are always preceded by a username, which is then followed by a colon or a space and then the email address, you can use that knowledge to restrict your matches.

What does a username look like?  You need to know if you're going to use it to find matches.  Let's say for now it is letters, numbers, dash, and underscore, it always starts with a letter, and is from 2 to 12 characters long. We also know it's got a colon or space after it. The regex for that is

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,11}[: ]
```

That would be followed by your email address which, it sounds like, is something you decide on and input because that's what you're looking for at the moment.

Your example of `test*****@example.com` would be

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,11}[: ]test.\+@example.com
```

or, if exactly 5 chars after "test"

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,11}[: ]test.....@example.com
```

Your original sample `***@example.com` is "any 3-char address at example.com" and would be

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,11}[: ]...@example.com
```

This would be a pain to retype that prefix all the time, so you'd want to wrap that in a script that uses `prefix + what_i_typed` as the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try this command line i used to found any thing in any files

```
 grep -r -i @example.com ./
```

Comment: In my example, this would find all 3 of the emails, not just 123@example.com.

Comment: @BotHam - You're not describing very well what you want to accomplish with this. If all you want to match is `123` just literally search for `grep -F 123@example.com ...` but that's not _really_ what you want. You will have to better describe what you're after.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully that makes it more clear. sorry for any confusion.